# What's the difference between revert <hash> and revert <head>?

Tags: git, github, revert, git-revert

I have 3 commits pushed to my repository.

- Commit3
- Commit2
- Commit1

So, if I try to revert **Commit2** with the command `git revert commit2Hash` it will give an alert in order to solve conflicts before merge.

But if I try to revert **Commit2** with the command `git revert HEAD~1` it will revert Commit2 directly without give me any conflict.

Please, why does that happen?

Comment: Because `HEAD~2` points to `<commit1>` here in your example

Comment: After your correction from `HEAD~2` to `HEAD~1` : both references now point to the same thing. No reason to have the slightest difference between these two syntaxes (`HEAD~1` and `<commit2Hash>`). Please double-check with a clean example and you'll see that both reverts behave exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

`HEAD~0` is your latest commit (aka simply `HEAD`)

`HEAD~2` represents the hash of the second commit counting from zero.

So, typing `git revert HEAD~2` you are trying to revert Commit1. That's the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I edited my post to Head~1. My question continues :D

Comment: @RenzoRodrigues Have you done `git revert --abort` after facing to the merge conflict?

Comment: that command will just abort a revert, right? I'd like to understand what happens behind the scenes when using hash instead of head.

I just found this link with an explanation. Some doubts still remain tho.
https://www.monarchdigital.com/blog/2015-04-21/understanding-how-git-revert-works-and-when-use-it

Comment: @RenzoRodrigues Yes, you are right. I only wanted to confirm that you don't make a mistake. The correct scenario means aborting of the first merge conflict (when you use hash) before trying to revert by hash. Because I see the possibility of successful aborting the commit1, while resolving the merge conflict. May you please provide some log, status and steps to reproduce?

Answer (score 0):

The output of `git log` without `--graph` is always linear, but the real history might be paralleled. When `git log` prints

```
commit3
commit2
commit1
```

`HEAD~1` could be equivalent to `commit1` instead of `commit2`. Use `git log --oneline --graph --decorate` to see the real history. It happens when `commit2` and `commit1` are diverged and `commit3` is a merge commit.